Cannot cannot push to Azure Container Registry from WSL (Ubuntu 24.04 LTS)
Receiving an authorization error:
unauthorized: {"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required, visit https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information."}]}
under the following conditions:

Admin user is enabled under the ACR's Access Keys settings
az acr health-check -n <myacr> -y initially failed but by installing both helm and notary in the WSL shell it ran without errors executing a pull along with validating the DNS lookup to the registry, fetch tokens, that the Docker Daemon is available and more
No issues with login to Docker or the ACR (cat ~/.docker/config.json returns two JSON stanzas under auths, one for index.docker.io and the other for my ACR)
az acr show --name <myacr> shows the key publicNetworkAccess as enabled, most policies disabled - nothing that seems off
Read through MSFT troubleshooting  and don't see any further ideas, not using a proxy and if a firewall were in the way seems like the health check wouldn't have completed

Appreciate any comments or suggestions!
Tried to follow a series of troubleshooting steps that are detailed above to give context to the question.

See if this helps- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71163896/how-to-authenticate-azure-container-registry-https-registry-azurecr-io-v2

Thank you, it did lead me to some additional references but I am using an admin account for testing rather than a token.

issue still there? if yes can you do this once- navigate to Access keys under your acr and then toggle Admin user off and on, then do docker logout myregistry.azurecr.io
docker login myregistry.azurecr.io -u  -p  and restart the docker desktop once

Further to our discussion in comments, double check that enable admin is properly configured
az acr update -n arkorgacr --admin-enabled true

ensure that the user or service principal you’re using has the correct permissions to push images. Specifically, the permission required is Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/write. You can verify this by checking the roles assigned to your user or service principal. It’s also worth double checking your network settings just to be sure everything is configured correctly.

Clear old docker cache to avoid any conflicts.
Log out and log back in to your acr
docker logout arkorgacr.azurecr.io
docker login arkorgacr.azurecr.io -u arkorgacr -p abcd



After re-authenticating, try pushing a test image to see if everything is working
docker push arkorgacr.azurecr.io/hello-acr:v1

If everything is set up correctly, this should allow you to connect, build, and push your sample image to ACR without encountering further authorization errors.


Found few additional MS docs, check them out once-

Authentication required error when trying to access Azure Container Registry
Frequently asked questions - Azure Container Registry
Troubleshoot Azure Container Registry authentication issues
Troubleshoot registry login

